# Django, using two databases with the same project

Tags: django

I am working in a big & complex django project. I have been asked to prepare it for accepting virtual data in order to test its production readiness (no one expected that decision from "upstairs", so everyone was caught off-guard).

For this, I have been asked to create another database (exact copy of the current one) in order to populate with millions of fake data.

I was wandering if possible to use the "fake-data DB" with the current project and let it "smartly" choose which database to use, depending on the url (maybe). For example:

`http://example.com/login/` would map data from the working DB and `http://test.example/com/login` would automatically map data to the "fake-data" DB. Both using the same django project and same Apache Virtualhost entry.

Does this make sense? Or should I create a whole new django project, instead (and modify Apache, too)?

PS: The project is currently in development process, so we can use the same server for testing and benchmarking..

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple databases in django. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#multiple-databases

But from your description, it sounds more like you just need 2 different environments. One non-production environment for accepting this virtual data, and another production environment. You can just have 2 different settings.py, and import the proper one depending on the environment.

Comment: Thanks, how can I import different settings.py depending on the url?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem well, then this is the approach I would take

1) In settings.py file (I am using mysql)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':{},
    'db1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Database_1',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',


    },
    'db2':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Database_2',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',


    }
}
```

2) In the urls.py file 
(sample URL patterns)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/login/$', views.xzy, {'database': 'db1'}),
    url(r'^com/login/$', views.xzy, {'database': 'db2'})

]
```

3) In `xzy(request, database)`, you can do the following:

```
records = Model.objects.using(database).all()
```

You can use 'database-routers' as well. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing

This should work in a simple environment. If you are using something like elasticsearch or solr, then this approach needs to modified.

Hope this helps.